# How to find the decreasing value of a pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have created an image that will help the understanding of the problem:

[image]

The number of circles can vary, what I need to find is the constant decreasing value...

Comment: What is the relation between radii? Is e.g. $r_1 - r_2 = r_3 - r_3 = \dotsm$? Or is $r_1/r_2 = r_2 / r_3 = \dotsm$? Or some fixed relation between areas? Something else? The problem can't be answered just with the data given.

Comment: I want to find the value of every unknown radius from "r1−r2=r3−r4=⋯"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let the number of circles = n
let the constant decreasing value if the radius be d,
Then you have an arithmetic progression with first and last terms known (60 and 10)
for an A.P.    $a_1$ ,$a_2$,$a_3$......$a_n$,
$a_n$=$a_1$ +(n-1)d           (Where 'd' is common difference)
so, rearranging,
60=10+(n-1)d
d=50/(n-1)
So your 'constant decreasing value' is given by 50/(n-1), where 'n' is the number of circles